# Install Pyembree with Anaconda

Tags: package, anaconda3, embree

I'm quite new to Anaconda. I was trying to install Pyembree using Anaconda and kept getting the following error. I use Windows 11 Pro. Any suggestions for how to install it?

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda config --set channel_priority strict

(base) C:\Users\User>conda install pyembree
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyembree

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```